# Navigation to Different "Versions" of the Same Screen React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I recently implemented navigation in my app using NavigatorIOS in React Native. However, I think I've encountered a problem. Say I have 10 nav buttons on my home screen. Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm assuming (since I haven't done the backend yet) that if I use the first button to navigate to the next screen (let's call it Second.js), wrote/saved some data, and then went back and navigated to Second.js with the second button, that data from before would still be there? If so, is there a way for each button to navigate to a different "version" of the same screen? For example, could each button go to its own version of Second.js so that each button has its own local data in its Second screen, or would I have to make Second1.js, Second2.js, Second3.js, etc.? If the former isn't possible, I'd need a fixed number of nav buttons, plus a lot of memory is wasted with all these new classes that are basically replicas of each other. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing: master screen, screen template, etc.